Framer Motion, Draging and Transforming
I have block of "slides" that are sliding on scrolling, and i also want them make draggable, right now when i drag and scroll at same time, or drag and scroll after, cards start to shaking because transformX from drag, and from scroll dont combine.
also i want to make cards loopable? right now i can drag indefinitely

import {  useRef } from "react";
import {
  useScroll,
  useTransform,
  motion,
 
} from "framer-motion";
import styles from "./style.module.scss";
import Image from "next/image";


export default function Index() {
  const container = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: container,
    offset: ["start end", "end start"],
  });

  const x1 = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [0, 150]);
  const x2 = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [0, -150]);
  const height = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.9], [50, 0]);


  return (
    <div ref={container} className={styles.slidingImages}>
      <motion.div style={{ x: x1 }} className={styles.slider} drag="x">
        {slider1.map((project, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={styles.project}
              style={{ backgroundColor: project.color }}
            >
              <div key={index} className={styles.imageContainer}>
                <Image
                  fill={true}
                  alt={"image"}
                  src={`/images/${project.src}`}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </motion.div>
      <motion.div style={{ x: x2 }} className={styles.slider} drag="x">
        {slider2.map((project, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={styles.project}
              style={{ backgroundColor: project.color }}
            >
              <div key={index} className={styles.imageContainer}>
                <Image
                  fill={true}
                  alt={"image"}
                  src={`/images/${project.src}`}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}

I tried to using onDragEnd event, but i didn't find out how to add value to existing transformX value
codesandbox

Can you reproduce your code on codesandbox and edit your question with the link for it?

added  codesandbox

@9uifranco did you check?
